# Select part of the URL inside an iframe tag

Tags: php, regex, iframe, preg-match

I need to capture an ID that is part of a URL that is inside an iframe tag.
I know this can be done with regex but I'm not very good at it, I made a few attempts but could not get a result, iframe would be this (ID may vary):

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/embed/ph57d6z9fa1349b" frameborder="0" height="481" width="608" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

And the ID I would like to get would be this:

```
ph57d6z9fa1349b
```

Comment: Is this overkill? [https://3v4l.org/v01sD](https://3v4l.org/v01sD). xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string with the regex.

```
$re = '/\<iframe[^\>]+src\="(.+?)\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)"/';
$str = '<iframe src="https://www.example.com/embed/ph57d6z9fa1349b" frameborder="0" height="481" width="608" scrolling="no"></iframe>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

If you want to list id codes (like 'ph57d6z9fa1349b') then you can do this:

```
<?php
$re = '/\<iframe[^\>]+src\="(.+?)\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)"/';
$str = '<iframe src="https://www.example.com/embed/ph57d6z9fa1349b" frameborder="0" height="481" width="608" scrolling="no"></iframe>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $id = $match[2];    // The required id code
    echo $id;           // Echo it
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches the source attribute and put your desided id in group 1.
`src=".+\/(.+?)"`

- The first part `src="` matches the start of attribute
- `.+\/` matches the URL body until the last slash (greedy)
- `(.+?)"` match your id (lazy) and the double quote that closes the attribute